# Gradle support in intellij forks

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, goland

I have GoGland, which is an IntelliJ based IDE.  I'm accustomed to great gradle support and highlighting in intellij, however, I don't see any such support in GoGland, nor in the plugin repository browswer for GoGland.

Is there a simple way to syntax highlight gradle files inside of Intellij's Gogland, which is not a full blown Java IDE?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to install [TextMate Bundles plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7221-textmate-bundles-support) in Gogland and set up [Groovy TextMate Bundle](https://github.com/textmate/groovy.tmbundle).

As for native support, we're not going to add Groovy support to Gogland. If you need Groovy or Gradle, you can use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate with [Go plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9568-go) installed that is pretty the same as Gogland.